# How to set the status bar to "Light" on Xcode 8 (preferably not by code)

Tags: ios, xcode, statusbar

is there any other way to set the status bar to "Light" on Xcode 8 than by using preferredStatusBarStyle. It would be great to do it through the Plist file for example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally figured it out, NO CODE NEEDED, you simply need to on your project settings set "**Status Bar Style**" to **Light** and go on your plist and add the row "**View controller-based status bar appearance**" with the value **NO**. That simple, no need to implement all your UIViewControllers...

Comment: This works for a simple app but ultimately having your top-level ViewControllers dictate the status bar color is better. What if the status bar style needs to change based on iOS version? Or what if you have some VCs that you want to change it? (i.e. if you have a light status bar and a screen to preview files like the Photos app, you may want a black backdrop and change the status bar style to light).

Answer (score 1):

Code *is* how you set it, so there's no point saying "preferably not by code". You don't do this according to *your* preference, but according to the API. That API is that every top-level view controller dictates how it wants the status bar to appear: if you want the status bar to be always light, you must override the `preferredStatusBarStyle` property in every view controller that will ever be top-level. (In the case of a navigation controller, you can readily do this by setting its bar style; for other built-in parent view controllers, your child view controller may be consulted automatically.)

Comment: I already know this way but it's just very unlikely that is the best solution is to overwrite all your viewcontrollers. I'm sure that there is a better way to do so.

Comment: It's not "just very unlikely". This is what you _do_. You may not like it, but you should just stop struggling, do it, and move on. There is no point downvoting me just because you don't happen to like the truth; it remains the truth.

Comment: The only "shortcut" way is to put everything inside a container view controller and let _it_ dictate the status bar, in once place. A UINavigationController can do this, for example, But what I said is still true.